# Oracle ADF - Create Child Entity on Parent Entity Creation

Tags: mysql, oracle-adf

I am building an ADF Fusion web application (12c) using a MySQL database.

To get auto-incremented PK values upon insert, I am using the method of assigning an "AutoIncrementProperty" property set (property "AI", value "true") to auto-increment PK fields.  All entities are extended from a class that overrides doDML().  That all works just fine, but FYI, this is the code I use for that:

```
protected void doDML(int i, TransactionEvent transactionEvent) {
    super.doDML(i, transactionEvent);

    if (i == DML_INSERT) {
        populateAutoincrementAtt();
    }
}

/*
* Determines if the Entity PK is marked as an autoincrement col
* and executes a MySQL function to retrieve the last insert id
*/
private void populateAutoincrementAtt() {
    EntityDefImpl entdef = this.getEntityDef();
    AttributeDef pk = null;
    //look for primary key with Autoincrement property set
    for (AttributeDef att : entdef.getAttributeDefs()) {
        if (att.isPrimaryKey() && (att.getProperty("AI") != null )) {
            pk = att;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (pk != null) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = 
             this.getDBTransaction()
                 .createPreparedStatement("SELECT last_insert_id()", 1)) {
            stmt.execute();
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    setAttribute(pk.getName(), rs.getInt(1));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

OK, that's not the problem.  That works as it should.

I have two entities with corresponding MySQL tables.  Let's call them "Person" and "Folder".  The Folder entity/table is recursive insomuch as it looks like this:

**Folder**

- *id* (auto-increment PK integer)
- *parentId*  (foreign key to a parent Folder object)
- *folderName*
- ...

And, the Person entity/table looks something like this:

**Person**

- *id* (auto-increment PK integer)
- *userName*
- *rootFolderId* (foreign key to Folder table)
- ...

So, a Person has a root Folder assigned to him/her.  (That Folder may then have a hierarchy of sub-folders.)

The problem I am having is that, when I create a Person entity, I want to create a new Folder entity, get its PK value, then assign that Integer to the new Person's rootFolderId attribute.

Should be really simple, no?

In the PersonImpl class (extends EntityImpl), I have the following method:

```
private Integer createRootFolder() {
    Integer newIdAssigned;

    String entityName = "com.my.model.entity.Folder";
    EntityDefImpl folderDef = EntityDefImpl.findDefObject(entityName);
    EntityImpl newFolder = (EntityImpl) folderDef.createInstance2(getDBTransaction(), null);
    newFolder.setAttribute("folderName", "ROOT");
    try {
        getDBTransaction().commit();
        newIdAssigned = (Integer) newCollection.getAttribute("Id");
    } catch (JboException ex) {
        getDBTransaction().rollback();
        newIdAssigned = null;
    }

    return newIdAssigned;
}
```

So, that method works just fine.  It does, indeed, insert a Folder object and returns its PK value.  The problem comes with when/where/how I call this method.

I can call it from the Create method of PersonImpl, like this:

```
protected void create(AttributeList attributeList) {
    Integer rootFolderId = null;

    rootFolderId = createRootFolder();

    super.create(attributeList);
    this.setRootFolderId(rootFolderID);
}
```

But, of course, this creates the root Folder object before the owning Person object is committed to the database.  So, if the Person is never committed, we have an orphaned Folder object that we just created for no reason.

I have tried calling it from doDML() in the PersonImpl class like this:

```
protected void doDML(int operation, TransactionEvent e) {
    Integer rootFolderId;

    super.doDML(operation, e);

    if (operation == DML_INSERT) {
        rootFolderId = createRootFolder();
        if (rootFolderId != null) {
            this.setRootCollectionId(rootCollID);
            getDBTransaction().commit();
        }
    }
}
```

But ... of course, when createRootFolder() calls commit(), this causes doDML() to fire again, and we get a recursive problem.  I've played with kludges like setting a flag to prevent recursive doDML() calls, but they all have problems.  And, I think there must be something much simpler I'm overlooking.

It would be ideal if I could do this declaratively somehow in the entities themselves, without code.  But, I should think the coded solution would be pretty simple.  I'm just not seeing it.

Any words?

Comment: why don't you work on viewObjects? create a viewLink between the two of them. in your case person master 1-1 relationship with child folder linked on person.folderid=folder.id. this way, when you create a new person as a row in the viewObject of persons, you can also create a folder row which will automatically take the value of the FK id from the master. Also, you can set the primary keys from sequences instead. look for SequenceImpl examples, much easier than what you wrote.

Comment: I have a 1-1 view link as you described.  But, this does not automatically generate the child.  Any approaches I've used to generate the child fail to automatically populate the FK.  This seems to be due to the fact that the child needs to be committed in order to retrieve its PK.  First glance is that your suggestion about sequences may solve this by allowing me to proactively set the PK.  I'll read up on it and see if I can sort it out.  Thanks again.

Comment: when generating the class for the master entity, choose to also define the create method. then overwrite it to set the primary key from a sequence. Now, every time you call to create a new row on any view object based on this entity, it will automatically populate this id from db. Every child of this ViewObject will also inherit the id on it's fk attribute linked on the viewLink, when it's create row method is called from the master. when exposing the viewLink, select the child to be visible in the master. Then you simply call it's create method from the master impl class.

Comment: here is example from Sequence: http://books.google.ro/books?id=MsEK0HJh2VAC&pg=PA334&lpg=PA334&dq=entity+object+create+sequenceimpl&source=bl&ots=1IEWOhZyol&sig=YjUb4s5YokcOH5fdmVEqfkE8luU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=d-WCVMbCKcn3UNPMgOAP&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=entity%20object%20create%20sequenceimpl&f=false

Comment: Check end of answer I edited with a better alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, with MUCH credit to @MihaiC, I've worked this out.

As MihaiC suggested, the best solution was to not use MySQL's auto-increment.  However, ADF does not support sequences for SQL92 flavor (which I must use for other reasons).  I looked at several approaches to simulate sequences and settled on a hybrid approach that works nicely.

Borrowing from this article:  http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-mysql/sequence , I created a simple table to store sequences to simulate this behavior.

Table:  _sequences

- name:  PK VARCHAR  (stores the sequence name)
- next:  INT (stores the next available value in the named sequence)
- inc: INT (stores the sequence's increment value)

I created a single record with the following values:

- name = "Folder_Seq";
- next = 100 (because I already had a few test records with low ID numbers)
- inc = 1 (don't know why you'd use anything else, but I could)

Then, it's simply a matter of looking up the value of "next" for a given named sequence, and incrementing that value for the next call.  I created a Sequence entity object for this purpose, based on the _sequences table.

Here's the code I used inside my PersonImpl class:

```
protected void doDML(int operation, TransactionEvent e) {
    if (operation == DML_INSERT) {
        // We do this only when we are ready to commit.
        Integer nextSeqVal = getNextFolderSequenceNumber();
        createRootFolder(nextSeqVal);
        setRootFolderId(nextSeqVal);
        // Need to add logic to bail out if something went wrong in the above steps.
    }
    // Nothing actually gets committed until we reach this line
    super.doDML(operation, e);
}

private Integer getNextFolderSequenceNumber() {
    SequenceImpl seq = getSequenceByName("Folder_Seq");
    Integer nextVal = seq.getNext();
    if (nextVal != null) {
        seq.setNext(nextVal + seq.getInc());
    } else {
        // handle this as an error
    }
    return nextVal;
}

// Looks up the Sequence entity by name
private SequenceImpl getSequenceByName(String seqName) {
    EntityDefImpl seqDef = SequenceImpl.getDefinitionObject();
    Key seqKey = SequenceImpl.createPrimaryKey(seqName);
    return (SequenceImpl) seqDef.findByPrimaryKey(getDBTransaction(), seqKey);
}

// Creates a Folder object with the passed Integer as its PK
private void createRootFolder(Integer pkID) {
    String entityName = "com.my.model.entity.Folder";
    EntityDefImpl folderDef = EntityDefImpl.findDefObject(entityName);    
    // I chose to fully-qualify EntityImpl since I have overriden oracle.jbo.server.EntityImpl
    oracle.jbo.server.EntityImpl newFolder = folderDef.createInstance2(getDBTransaction(), null);
    newFolder.setAttribute("FolderName", "ROOT");  // Because I want all root folders to be named "ROOT"
    newFolder.setAttribute("Id", pkID);
}
```

So, in doDML() of the master Person entity, I do four things prior to committing to the database:

- Get the next available sequence number for the Folder_Seq sequence.
- Increment the "next" value in the corresponding Sequence entity.
- Create a new Folder entity and set its PK with that next-in-sequence value.
- Set this value as the foreign key "RootFolderId" attribute value.

Then, if all of the above succeeds, all is committed to the database when super.doDML() is called.

That is, I believe this logic to be sound.

I am somewhat concerned that, in a multi-user environment, it might be possible for two users to get the same next-in-sequence value, causing a problem when the second person tried to commit.  This would be possible if ADF allowed the following order of events:

1. User A gets the "next" value of ... say ... 1001.
2. User B gets the same value since User A has not committed his incremented value.
3. User A commits all changes.
4. User B sees an error when she tries to commit since the PK 1001 now exists in the database.

I don't know if ADF would allow one user to begin doDML() while another user is in the middle of that procedure.  Not concerned about it for this application, but I wouldn't trust this for a high-volume multi-user application without doing further research.

Comment: Congrats on finding a solution! If you can ensure the sequence is retrieved and set only just before the commit happens, you can avoid the concurrency issue. that is why i recommend to create a custom method in your viewObjects instead of entities. You can then control the flow exactly as you need, and save the data with a simple try{ this.getDBTransaction().commit(); }catch{this.getDBTransaction().rollback();} just before exiting the method.

Comment: a good practice would be to also include the incrementing of the sequence value from the seq table viewImpl row, in the try{} such that it would only increment if saving is possible. Then if the data can't be saved, it would rollback everything on the rows, including the new sequence. If all is ok and data can be saved, the changes on the viewObj rows would persist to the entities

Answer (score 1):

Even though you already found a solution, I would like to show my own take on this: not using code in entities at all, just code and methods from `ViewObjects`.

I created the 3 tables: `Person`, `Folder` and `Sequences` as you have described them. I then created `EntityObjects` and `ViewObjects` for all of them.

`PersonView` and `FolderView` are tuned to not return any rows, i.e. used only for insert.

`SequenceView` is tuned to always return maximum one row.

`PersonView` and `FolderView` are populated from simple query: `select * from table`.

`SequenceView` is populated from simple query as above but I have defined a custom `ViewCriteria` on it, to retrieve only the row with the matching name. I can't post pictures at the moment to show you, but the `VC` only does: `where name=:p_seq_name`.

Next step is to define method to retrieve the sequences. You do this by writing a custom method inside the implementation class of the Sequence ViewObject (`SequencesViewImpl`):

```
//returns a sequence view object row, always one
public SequencesViewRowImpl getNextSequenceRow(String seqName) {
    this.setp_seq_name(seqName);
    this.setApplyViewCriteriaName("ByNameViewCriteria");
    this.executeQuery();
    final SequencesViewRowImpl seqRow = (SequencesViewRowImpl)this.first();
    return seqRow;
}
```

Next, we expose our `ViewObjects` in the service, `AppModule` (i know, i didn't rename it - so we can use their specific methods inside the associated implementation class (`AppModuleImpl`).

**We must expose the sequence view twice**, so that we are dealing with two distinct rows, and don't have to set and reset the same row (if we were using one). So far, our `AppModuleImpl` class should contain the following `getters` for our `views`:

```
/**
 * Container's getter for FolderView1.
 * @return FolderView1
 */
public FolderViewImpl getFolderView1() {
    return (FolderViewImpl)findViewObject("FolderView1");
}

/**
 * Container's getter for PersonView1.
 * @return PersonView1
 */
public PersonViewImpl getPersonView1() {
    return (PersonViewImpl)findViewObject("PersonView1");
}

/**
 * Container's getter for SequencesView1.
 * @return SequencesView1
 */
public SequencesViewImpl getSequencesView1() {
    return (SequencesViewImpl)findViewObject("SequencesView1");
}

/**
 * Container's getter for SequencesView2.
 * @return SequencesView2
 */
public SequencesViewImpl getSequencesView2() {
    return (SequencesViewImpl)findViewObject("SequencesView2");
}
```

Let's now create a new `Person` row, just by using the `viewObjects` methods. (write code in `AppModuleImpl` class)

```
public void createPerson() {
    final SequencesViewRowImpl personSeq = this.getSequencesView1().getNextSequenceRow("Person_Seq"); //a person sequence row, note that we are getting View1, we will use View2 for Folders.
    final PersonViewRowImpl personRow = (PersonViewRowImpl)this.getPersonView1().createRow(); //create a new row in memory

    //set attributes for the new person row
    personRow.setId(personSeq.getNext());
    personRow.setUsername("TestUser");
    final Integer rootFolderId = this.createRootFolder(); //create a new folder row and retrieve the folderId
    personRow.setRootFolderId(rootFolderId);
    this.getPersonView1().insertRow(personRow); //actually insert the row, caches the result onto the entity, when commited it will be saved.

    this.incrementSequences(); //increment the sequences

    try {
        this.getDBTransaction().commit(); //if all is ok save all the rows to the database
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.getDBTransaction().rollback(); //if anything went wrong, rollback everything including the incrementing of the seq
        //let the user know the data couldn't be saved, so he can try again; this should happen only when the primary key constraints have failed validation, since you should ensure data type and length validation eigther from page or other sources.
        throw new JboException("Person with id = "+personSeq.getNext()+" or Folder with id = "+rootFolderId +" was already saved. Please try again.");
    }
}
```

The `createRootFolder()` method:

```
private Integer createRootFolder() {
    final SequencesViewRowImpl folderSeq = this.getSequencesView2().getNextSequenceRow("Folder_Seq"); //View2 on the same Object for Folders
    final FolderViewRowImpl folderRow = (FolderViewRowImpl)this.getFolderView1().createRow(); //create and set the attributes for the new folder
    folderRow.setId(folderSeq.getNext());
    folderRow.setFolderName("ROOT");
    this.getFolderView1().insertRow(folderRow);
    return folderSeq.getNext(); //return the new folder id
}
```

And finally the increment sequences method:

```
private void incrementSequences() {
    final SequencesViewRowImpl personSeq = this.getSequencesView1().getNextSequenceRow("Person_Seq");
    final SequencesViewRowImpl folderSeq = this.getSequencesView2().getNextSequenceRow("Folder_Seq");

    personSeq.setNext(personSeq.getNext() + personSeq.getInc());
    folderSeq.setNext(folderSeq.getNext() + folderSeq.getInc());
}
```

Finallu, I've exposed the `createPerson()` method in the client interface of the service (`AppModule`) and dragged it as a button in a page. I've started from id's 1 for both person and folder, then changed it to 100 for folder the third time. Results are below:

Person Table:

```
ID | USERNAME | ROOT_FOLDER_ID
1  | TestUser |1
2  | TestUser |2
3  | TestUser |100
```

Folder Table:

```
ID | PARENT_ID | FOLDER_NAME
1  |           |ROOT
2  |           |ROOT
100|           |ROOT
```

Sequences Table:

```
NAME      | NEXT | INC
Folder_Seq| 101  |1
Person_Seq| 4    |1
```

This way, you have complete control of what is going on with your rows, objects and data. If anything fails to validate when reaching the entities or the database from the rows, everything get's rollback so you don't increment the sequences if nothing was saved.

Furthermore, this should ensure that concurrency is not a problem, since everything gets invoked sequentially and saved at the end. So unless you have hundreds of users that hit that button in the same nanosecond, I don't think it's possible to obtain already saved id's and get a constraint validation.

One problem could arise if there is lag between the pressing of the buttons, but this shouldn't happen for such small objects and query for the sequence table. Of course, if you can extensively test this, go ahead, I'm interested in the results as well, BUT I believe you will have a hard time getting the right scenario for this particular test.

In any case, the `throw new JboException` will let the user know if anything went wrong, 
and he can retry saving the new person.

---

**EDIT**

I have tested it with multiple user clicks at the same time, and indeed the exception is thrown sometimes, although were rarely. The code ensures that no duplicates can ever enter the database.

The error will tell the user to try again. But again, this happens very infrequently, once every 100 clicks or so from 2 users, who were spamming the button.

Of course we need more users, but it should be fine. Regardless, wrong data does not get to the database, and the user does not loose his input data. He just has to try again.

The error also appears in your server logs like this:

**ADF: Adding the following JSF error message: Person with id = 61 or Folder with id = 158 was already saved. Please try again.**

So you can monitor them.

---

I will delete my older answer since it wasn't optimal. :) Had time to think and I think this is the best solution. Also I am sorry for huge answer, might be hard to follow. If you have any questions let me know.